# How can I align divs with position:fixed side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

I need a way to get child divs with `position:fixed` to float left side-by-side. If one of the child divs is `display:none`, then the rest of the child divs move over.

`position:fixed` has them all overlapping even with `display:inline-block` or `float:left`.

And `position:absolute` and `position:sticky` moves them with their parent div.

Here is a gif of what I am attempting to do:

[image]

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent-1">
    <div class="child-1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-2">
    <div class="child-2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-3">
    <div class="child-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using position fixed for this? Should the container be fixed when you scroll?

Comment: I am using position:fixed to take the child divs out of the document flow. If they are not position:fixed, they will move up and down with their parents, rather than separately left to right.

Comment: If this is the structure of the html and this is the design you are attempting with that structure, then, you have to dynamically calculate the the top, bottom, left and right position of the child div.

Comment: They are overlapping probably because, their left, right, top and bottom values are same and so they are fixed to the the same part in the screen

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` moved the element completely out of the flow and aligns them `fixed` to the viewport. Move `position: fixed` to the parent and align the child items in row by using flexbox on the parent.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.parent-2').classList.toggle('d-none');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}


/* for visualization purpose only */
[class*="parent-"] {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent-1">
    <div class="child-1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-2">
    <div class="child-2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-3">
    <div class="child-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>


<button>Click here to show/hide element 2</button>
```

Comment: This will work great if instead of a button trigger it was a tab to a new input focus. Is there a way to change that? If the user tabs from one input to a different input it will trigger the same function.

Comment: the button was justa dded for demo purpose. you can bidn the same script to any other event you like...

Comment: I'm terrible at javascript but I will try to figure it out Lol Thanks for your help!